# 'java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:/home/jenkins/workspace/testCases/41/1/1.in' when deleting files over jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a jenkins server on a linux host.I try to delete some files using jenkins pipeline from jenkins dashboard.my pipeline script goes like follwing:

```
node(){
      int deleteCount=0
      while(deleteCount < 10)
      {
         try{
             deleteCount++
             sh script:'rm -rf ../testCases/41/*'
             boolean fileExist = fileExists '../testCases/41/1/1.in'
             if(!fileExist) break
         }catch(err)
         {
            sleep 1
         }
}
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/1/1.in', text: 'bookstore'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/1/1.out', text: 'databaseName:bookstore'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/1/1.isPublic', text: '1'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/1/2.in', text: 'bookstore2'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/1/2.out', text: 'databaseName:bookstore2'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/1/2.isPublic', text: '1'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/2/1.in', text: 'book\n5\nid int(11)\nauthor 
varchar(255)\ntitle varchar(255)\npublisher varchar(255)\npublihserYear 
int(11)'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/2/1.out', text: 'table:book'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/2/1.isPublic', text: '1'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/2/2.in', text: 'book2\n3\nid int(11)\ntitle 
varchar(255)\nprice int(11)'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/2/2.out', text: 'table:book2'
writeFile file: '../testCases/41/2/2.isPublic', text: '1'
........
```

when I run this script, it turns out that,sometimes it can be completed successfully but sometimes failed,the error logs are as following:

```
1
+ rm -rf ../testCases/41
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1/1.in': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1/1.out': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1/1.isPublic': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1/2.in': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1/2.out': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1/2.isPublic': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/1': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2/1.in': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2/1.out': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2/1.isPublic': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2/2.in': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2/2.out': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2/2.isPublic': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/2': Permission denied
rm: can't remove '../testCases/41/3/1.in': Permission denied
.......`1`


[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 1 sec
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
/home/jenkins/workspace/testCases/41/1/1.in
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
atsun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.ja
 va:214)
.....
at hudson.FilePath$37.invoke(FilePath.java:1912)
at hudson.FilePath$37.invoke(FilePath.java:1908)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2739)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at ......remote call to Channel to /10.9.186.111(Native Method)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
Caused: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /home/jenkins/workspace/testCases/41/1/1.in at hudson.remoting.Channel@63880c2b:Channel to /10.9.186.111
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:993)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
at hudson.FilePath.write(FilePath.java:1908)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.WriteFileStep$Execution.run(WriteFileStep.java:94)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.WriteFileStep$Execution.run(WriteFileStep.java:84)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I just want to delete old files before writing new data,but this porblem really confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied means you don' have the right on that folder, perhaps you are not their owner? can you run the command as root?

Comment: yes,I started jenkins in root and gave all the files a 777 permissions.sometings I can delete the file successfully but sometimes I cannot

Answer (score 1):

it is clear that Jenkins does not have rights on those files.
I faced this issue once I tested jenkins by running with root user temporarily.

Go to Jenkins Config file (Red Hat - /etc/sysconfig/jenkins), and see which user you are using to run Jenkins). File which cannot be deleted might belong to some other user.

Delete those files manually with appropriate user and you should be good.